# How to call service from controller?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a controller class `MovieSearchCtrl`, in this class is a function:

```
returnMovies(query): any {
    return MovieSeat.MovieSearchService.getMovies(query);
}
```

I also have a service class `MovieSearchService`, in this class is a function:

```
getMovies(query) {
    let baseUrl = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    return this.$resource(baseUrl + "search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=" + query + "&callback=angular.callbacks._0");
}
```

In `the constructor of the MovieSearchCtrl` class I want to return:

```
this.results = this.returnMovies(query);
```

How do I use the return data from the `getMovies()` function into the `MovieSearchCtrl` class?

Answer (score 1):

Just Inject MovieSearchService into MovieSearchCtrl and then call the getMovies()
like so:

```
.controller('MovieSearchCtrl ',function(MovieSearchService, $scope){
      $scope.movies =[];
      $scope.search={}; //ng-model for your input

      MovieSearchService.getMovies($scope.search.query).then(function(res){
      $scope.movies = res.data;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.factory('MoviesAPI', function($resource, apiHost) {
  return $resource(apiHost + '/movies/:Id'); 
});
```

To be able to use your service in the controller you have to inject it.

```
.controller('myController', function($routeParams,MoviesAPI) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.movies = [];
        var myMoviesResource = MoviesAPI.query();

        vm.getMovies = function (){
              myMoviesResource.$promise
                .then(function(response) {
                 vm.movies = response;

                }, function(error) {

                    // doSomething
                });
              };


        };

    });
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Two steps.

1. if it is in a separate module, make it a dependency in your module definition

   ```
   angular.module('MovieSearchCtrl', ['MovieSearchService']);
   ```
2. inject it in your controller definition

   ```
   MovieSearchCtrl(MovieSearchService){
      this.movies = MovieSearchService.getMovies():
   }
   angular.controller('MovieSearchCtrl', MovieSearchCtrl);
   ```